VSCode & JS : Intellisense in composed modules?
My project setup at work (legacy code) is like this:
Services folder, index.js
const dependencyFn = require("dependency-fn");

const makeFn = require("./makeFn")
const fn = makeFn({ dependencyFn });

module.exports = { fn }


makeFn.js
module.exports = ({ dependencyFn }) => (input) => {
  const val = dependencyFn.doSomething(input);
  return val;
}

The problem is that in makefn.js I lose Intellisense for dependencyFn and can't see its methods.
Any way to solve this other than switching it all to Typescript (project is too big)?

It's not losing IntelliSense... It's just that in makeFn.js the dependencyFn could be anything, including undefined. You should JSDoc the function at makeFn.js and hint what dependencyFn should be, then IntelliSense will reveal the right result.

You should try documenting the function at makeFn.js.
It should tell IntelliSense what dependencyFn actually is. Because the way it is is telling that it could be anything.
Like this:
/**
 * @param {{ dependencyFn: Awaited < import("dependency-fn") > ["default"] }} param0
 */
module.exports = ({ dependencyFn }) => (input) => {
   const val = dependencyFn.doSomething(input);
   return val;
}

PS.: Of course, it looks like dependencyFn is a dynamic value. Which is pretty hard to documentate. You'll probably have to delve in JSDoc to better achieve what you want.
Example of anonymous detection:
/**
 * @template { { [ ALIAS in keyof anonymousType]: anonymousType[ALIAS] } } anonymousType
 * @param {{ dependencyFn: anonymousType }} param0
 */
module.exports = ({ dependencyFn }) => (input) => {
   const val = dependencyFn.doSomething(input);
   return val;
}

